# Init database for test purpose during maven test phase

Tags: sql, spring, unit-testing, maven, hsqldb

I am trying to do the following :

- execute some database scripts during mvn test phase into hsqldb
- use that database for test purpose

  I was able to configure maven so that each time test phase is called all scripts are executed successfully, but (of course there is a BUT), all my tests failed.

My configurations :

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Plugin maven for sql -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- Dependency to jdbc driver -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>${hsql-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sweetdev_skill_db;shutdown=false</url>
                <settingsKey>hsql-db-test</settingsKey>
                <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
                <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!--  Create integration test data before running the tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>create-integration-test-data</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db;shutdown=false</url>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                        <fileset>
                            <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>create.sql</include>
                                <include>insert.sql</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!--  Drop data after executing tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                        <fileset>
                            <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>drop.sql</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

spring config for test :

```
<bean id="datasource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver">
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db"></property>
    <property name="username" value="sa">
    </property>
    <property name="password" value="">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <!-- use testingSetup pu -->
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testingSetup" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Output :

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] [clean:clean]
    [INFO] Deleting directory D:\dev\projects\project-data\target
    [INFO] [resources:resources]
    [INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] [compiler:compile]
    [INFO] Compiling 62 source files to D:\dev\projects\project-data\target\classes
    [INFO] [resources:testResources]
    [INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] [sql:execute {execution: create-integration-test-data}]
    [INFO] Executing file: D:\dev\projects\project-data\src\test\resources\sql\create.sql
    [INFO] Executing file: D:\dev\projects\project-data\src\test\resources\sql\insert.sql
    [INFO] 230 of 230 SQL statements executed successfully
    [INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
    [INFO] Compiling 12 source files to D:\dev\projects\project-data\target\test-classes
    [INFO] [surefire:test]
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\dev\projects\project-data\target\surefire-reports
```

But then all my test fail. I need your help to figure out why it doesn't work and help me find solution. Thank you

---

@AndrewLogvinov

Here is one of test output :

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Test set: com.ideo.sweetdevskill.data.impl.TestAcquisitionDAOImpl
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.17 sec <<< FAILURE!
    testGetListAcquisitionByUser(com.ideo.sweetdevskill.data.impl.TestAcquisitionDAOImpl)  Time elapsed: 0.148 sec  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
        at com.ideo.sweetdevskill.data.impl.TestAcquisitionDAOImpl.testGetListAcquisitionByUser(TestAcquisitionDAOImpl.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare these lines in your config. The database names are different, therefore two different databases are being used.

```
<url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sweetdev_skill_db;shutdown=false</url>

<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db"></property>
```

Comment: Thanks again, but I have intentionally changed the database name for edit purpose (by that I mean, I changed it when I was writing my post, I only forgot to change the database name in this part which is the actual database name of my appli). So, I actually use one database. What I suspect right now is either scripts are rolled back before I start running my tests  (perhaps it was never commited despite this : <autocommit>true</autocommit>) either scripts are executed under other schema (I don't know why).

Comment: Hello again, right now I am getting the following error while trying to launch maven test phase :         ERROR C:org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter Table not found in statement

Comment: Try with a file database with an absulute path jdbc:hsqldb:file:/folder/db;shutdown=true which stores the data when a process is terminated, and allows you to see what's being stored in the .log file of the database.

Comment: I have done what you suggested and it works fine. I wonder why I have those errors when I use memory. I will post solution later for those who may need it. Again thanks for your help !

Comment: I notice a very strange behaviour, even after droping all tables in my database after maven test phase, I was able to run test with junit on eclipse. Even stranger, maven test was successfull even after I delete configuration in pom (the one which launches all scripts ). I suspect that once I scripts are run, files will be stored somewhere. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: In my example, the database files are stored in the directory named /folders

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention my dataSource was just pointing to wrong databas files ('t was all my fault). Anyway, I did what you suggested and it worked :)

Comment: Even though I decided to use file for this case, there're still things I don't understand. When I used in memory database (jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db) and when I add ifexists=true on the second execution, scripts are executed as if the in memory database previously used was actually created (I skiped test so that I got no error so post integration execution can be run), but when I try to use the same database in my persistence unit I got an exception and following error Database does not exists: mem:db any idea ?

Comment: ifexists is for file databases. Has no effect on mem: databases.

Comment: Uh, that's strange, perhaps I misinterpret what I see but, actually when I add ifexists=true on in memory database it throws exception.

Comment: A mem: database is destroyed when the process terminates, but a file: database survives. It seems you populate and use the database in different processes.

Answer (score 2):

I have promised to post the solution, so here I am.

Let's start with ths spring config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--beans followed by all xml schemas here -->
    <!-- HSQL datasource for test purpose-->
    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:db" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ============================ ENTITY MANAGER    ================================= -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <!-- use testingSetup pu -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testingSetup" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- all other things you may need-->
</beans>
```

persistence.xml would have same structure as for application
inside pom.xml of the project : (I only include here the related part :

```
    <!-- Plugin maven for sql -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Dependency to jdbc driver -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>${hsql-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${basedir}/db;shutdown=true</url>
                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                <settingsKey>hsql-db-test</settingsKey>
                <!--all executions are ignored if -DskipTests=true-->
                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!--  Create test data before running the tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>create-test-compile-data</id>
                    <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${basedir}/db;shutdown=true</url>
                        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>

                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                        <detail>true</detail>
                        <fileset>
                            <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>script-create.sql</include>
                                <include>script-insert.sql</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--  Drop test data after running the tests include hereafter -->

        </plugin>
```

Thanks for your help.